# How can I determine the name of the dll from its disassembled code?

Tags: windows, dll

For example, I have a piece of disassembled code at base address 0x77B50000, which is a base address of a dll, how can I know which dll it is from the assembly codes?

Comment: In the VS debugger, use Debug + Windows + Modules.  Click the Address column to sort the modules by load address.  Always be specific about what kind of tooling you use.

Answer (score 1):

`LoadLibrary` returns a `HMODULE`, which is just the base address of the library, so if you've got the base address then you can cast it to a `HMODULE` and call [GetModuleFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).